# C# List<string> Memory not collected

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

This code allocates memory, but never frees the memory.  How do I force collection of the memory, GC.Collect() does not seem to work either.

I have reviewed many posts that ask this question but everyone answers that the garbage collector will take care of the memory, but it never does.

```
    var list = new List<string>();

    for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
      list.Add("really long string..................................................................................................");
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
      list[i] = null;
    }

    list.Clear();
```

Comment: call `GC.Collect()` to force garbage collection.

Comment: It _does_ collect the memory, _when it wants to_. And you can't really predict when, but it's okay. Just let the GC do its job.

Comment: Is the above your real test? Adding a single constant interned string?

Comment: Think about it this way: What are the chances that you would be the one to discover that GC doesn't work for a simple example like this?

Comment: *does not seem to work* is a very vague statement.  You really haven't explained what you observed and how you reached your conclusions.

Comment: Copy paste this code into an app.  Start the app and check the memory usage of the app, run the code above and measure again.  The memory goes up, and never comes back down.  Isn't that the definition of a memory leak?  If anyone can get this code to release the memory it allocates, then I would consider that fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the [code of `List<T>.Clear`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,303):

```
// Clears the contents of List.
public void Clear() {
    if (_size > 0)
    {
        Array.Clear(_items, 0, _size); // Don't need to doc this but we clear the elements so that the gc can reclaim the references.
        _size = 0;
    }
    _version++;
}
```

As you can see, the array is kept allocated as-is. This is done for efficiency reasons. The array is already allocated, there's no need let the GC collect it as it will probably be needed again.

You can set the `Capacity` property to force it to reallocate a new array. This will actually *add* memory pressure (unless you set it to 0) until the previous array gets collected. Here's the [code for reference](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,110):

```
// Gets and sets the capacity of this list.  The capacity is the size of
// the internal array used to hold items.  When set, the internal 
// array of the list is reallocated to the given capacity.
// 
public int Capacity {
    get {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= 0);
        return _items.Length;
    }
    set {
        if (value < _size) {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.value, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_SmallCapacity);
        }
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        if (value != _items.Length) {
            if (value > 0) {
                T[] newItems = new T[value];
                if (_size > 0) {
                    Array.Copy(_items, 0, newItems, 0, _size);
                }
                _items = newItems;
            }
            else {
                _items = _emptyArray;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As for your *really long string*, it's just a reference to an interned string... The list will store 8 bytes per item anyway (assuming a 64-bit system).

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  So I should call list.Clear(); then list.Capacity = 0;?  It doesn't seem to change the result.  Ideally I would want an extension method that would wrap of of this into one call.

Comment: Ideally, you should totally ignore all of this since as far as I can tell, you have no problem in the first place. Just let the runtime deal with memory allocation/deallocation. As I said, setting the capacity to zero will most probably both decrease performance *and* raise memory pressure the next time you'll fill the list. Messing with the GC is an advanced topic, but your question unfortunately shows a lack of understanding of the .Net memory model. If you have a *specific* issue, then post another question, after reading about [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271659).

Comment: I discovered this issue after trying to parse a large text file.  The logic is built to discover related items and adding them to a list, once all related items are collected they are written to another file, the list clears, and move on to the next set of related items.  The list clear() does not free the memory and eventually the app runs out of memory.  So I put together this simple example to demonstrate this problem.

Comment: Ok, so what you need to do in that case, is to use a memory profiler (such as dotMemory). Take a snapshot of your app *after* you clear the list and it'll show you what's retaining memory. Alternatively, you could: 1) make sure the code executes in 64-bit mode (untick the prefer 32-bit box) - this is just a workaround, 2) initialize the list with the maximum number of lines you know it could contain by using the constructor which accepts a capacity (if possible), 3) rework your algorithm so it's less memory-hungry (this is always possible but it may prove difficult).

Comment: Lucas, thank you for the suggestions.  I have already proceeded with 64 bit to buy me some more space and the process did run.  But I am still troubled by the fact that there seems no way to clear the list from memory.  I only decided to post this question in a different way (very simple example) because all answers I found on the web proclaimed that calling GC.Collect or setting the items to null would work, but it just doesn't.  The memory claimed by the app will never go down.

Answer (score -2):

If you explicitly call `GC.Collect()` it doesn't mean that it's going to be collected immediately. GC will decide when to collect...

Comment: While this is true, there isn't even anything that can be collected in this case.

Comment: @Servy: Actually the [documentation on GC.Collect()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx) does say: *Forces an immediate garbage collection of all generations.*.  It's not like Java where it's merely a hint to the GC.

Comment: GC.Collect() does not free the memory allocated by the sample code I provided.  I would think it would since I have set all references to null.