# Multidimensional List of ints C#

Tags: c#, list

First of all i searched through the questions and I haven't found the thing I need , maybe it doesn't exist haha but i'll give it a shot.I am new to C# and I am coming from C++, got highschool experience.

In C++ I had `Vector<int> T[];` so I could create a list with a size that it wasn't know; and make something like this and not wasting space; to be more exact

```
T[0][....];
T[1][...];

1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 
2 4 1 5
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I am trying to do this in C# and It doesn't seem to work; I have tried this so far:

```
 public class myints
    {
        public int x { get; set; }
    }

  public List<myints[]> T = new List<myints[]>();

  T[i].Add(new myints() { x = i });
```

I wanna be able to add stuff and then use `Count()` in a `for` to see how many elemts  I have in a `T[i]`. like `T[i].size()`... Is this possible?

the program says System.Array does not contain a definition for Add

Comment: Arrays are of fixed-size, just like in C++ BTW. Use `List<List<T>>`.

Comment: List<T> as Lucas Trzesniewski suggested above is what you are looking for.  But your comment about no space being wasted is not correct.  List<T> is like a resizing array.  When .Add is called on a full List<T>, the framework doubles the allocated size, and I believe never shrinks it (I'd have to check the .NET source to be sure).  When it is no longer referenced however, it will of course be garbage collected.

Comment: This has a nice explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665299/are-2-dimensional-lists-possible-in-c

Comment: @ClayVerValen it never does shrink it by itself since it would be [wasteful to do so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34233735/3764814), but you can set the `Capacity` property yourself if you *really know* it's a good idea in a particular case.

Comment: @Lucas Trzesniewski I went with -  public List<List<int>> T = new List<List<int>>();  -  and using T[i].Add(j); under 2 fors, to add stuff and I'm getting a out of range() out of index?? error when I'm doing this at the T[i].Add(j);
... what do I do?

Comment: @rakuens use the debugger :) `i` is out of bounds for `T`, like the error says.

Comment: @Lucas - Agreed.  That is what I had read, but often sources on the web are incorrect about such matters, so without taking the time to look at the .NET source, I did not care to state it definitively.  It was only the OP's statement regarding "... not wasting space ..." that caused my concern as it showed a poor understanding of the algorithm(s) used behind resizing arrays (in other languages) or List<T> (in .NET) work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example creates a list with a number of sublists of varying length and should serve as a good starting point for what you want to do.

```
List<List<int>> mainlist = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> counter = new List<int>() { 5, 4, 7, 2 };
int j = 0;

// Fill sublists
foreach(int c in counter)
{
    mainlist.Add(new List<int>(c));
    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++ )
        mainlist[j].Add(i);
    j++;
 }
```

You could also add initialized lists to the main list

```
List<List<int>> mainlist = new List<List<int>>();
mainlist.Add(new List<int>() { 1, 5, 7 });
mainlist.Add(new List<int>() { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 });
mainlist.Add(new List<int>() { 0, 0, 0 });
```

Comment: Can I do this without knowing the length? what I'm doing is reading nodes and adding them slowly to the list , this example gave me a better understanding though. Why do I have to add a 3rd list to the list? if there are already 2 declared

Comment: yes, these Lists dynamically grow as you add things, welcome to the nice world of c#

Comment: You do not 'have to' add a 3rd list. This is just an example. You can add as many lists as you like.